# CKEditor error creating dialog

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have the following test script:

```js
    var field = {id: "html1"};
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(field.id);
    var dialogObj = new CKEDITOR.dialog(editor, 'smiley');
```

I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dir' of undefined
    at CKEDITOR.dialog (ckeditor.js:573)
    at testCKE.html:24

I am using the full version 4.6.2 (12 Jan 2017)

dir seems to be an element of editor.lang
I experimented with setting config.language and config.defaultLanguage

I tried it with and without jquery, no difference

The editor opens fine and appears to work.
What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE: found an answer, see below. Still interested if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the dialog to work using code based on the samples/old/dialog files, cutdown version:

```
var field = {id: "html1"};
CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( ev ){
    var editor = ev.editor;

    // Listen for the "pluginsLoaded" event, so we are sure that the
    // "dialog" plugin has been loaded and we are able to do our
    // customizations.
    editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function() {

        // If our custom dialog has not been registered, do that now.
        if ( !CKEDITOR.dialog.exists( 'myDialog' ) ) {

            CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'myDialog', function(){
                return  {title: 'My Dialog',
                    minWidth: 400,
                    minHeight: 200,
                    contents:[
                        {
                            id: 'tabA',
                            label: 'TabA',
                            title: 'TabA',
                            elements: [
                                {
                                    id: 'button1',
                                    type: 'button',
                                    label: 'Button Field'
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                };
            } );
        }

        // Register the command used to open the dialog.
        editor.addCommand( 'myDialogCmd', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'myDialog' ) );

        // Add the a custom toolbar buttons, which fires the above
        // command..
        editor.ui.add( 'MyButton', CKEDITOR.UI_BUTTON, {
            label: 'My Dialog',
            command: 'myDialogCmd'
        });
    });
});

var editor = CKEDITOR.replace(field.id);
```